# Correlations between several dataframes within a list object

Tags: r

I have 4 dataframes that I decided to put within a list object.

I want to compute correlations between each dataframes and all the others. More specifically I want to compute the correlation between the `dataframe_1` and the 2 others. The same thing between the `dataframe_2` and the 3 others and so on, until all combinations are made.

Example of Script:

```
df1=matrix(data = rnorm(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5); colnames(df1)=c("a", "b","c", "d", "e")
df2=matrix(data = rnorm(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5); colnames(df2)=c("a", "b","c", "d", "e")
df3=matrix(data = rnorm(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5); colnames(df3)=c("a", "b","c", "d", "e")
df4=matrix(data = rnorm(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5); colnames(df4)=c("a", "b","c", "d", "e")
list_tab=list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

I try with `lapply(list_tab, function(x)cor(x))` But I didn't get what I was expecting.

I want to get a list with these objects:

- `cor(df1, df2)`
- `cor(df1, df3)`
- `cor(df1, df4)`
- `cor(df2, df3)`
- `cor(df2, df4)`
- `cor(df3, df4)`

It's boring to do that one by one, so I'm looking for a straightforward way to that.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but wouldn't it be better to use an array for this sort of structure?

Comment: Yes, I could have, but I don't think it would have been better. Because I'd have been constraint to add the supplementary dimnames argument (in the function array), whereas with list there is no argument else to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one-liner computes all pairwise correlations between matrices in `list_tab`, including correlations of each matrix with itself.

```
lapply(list_tab, function(DF) Map(cor, list_tab, list(DF)))
```

Comment: It works, even though it give the same correlations many times, Thanks!

Comment: @AchilleNyouma The pairwise correlations are equal but the correlation matrices are not. I have just compared all versus all and it always returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I was talking as well about pairwise correlations  which will finally appear two times. But I can easily manage that.